# Vertical bootstrap carousel with number of items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make vertical carousel based on [ShowManySlideOneCarousel](https://github.com/rtpHarry/Bootstrap3-ShowManySlideOneCarousel) (which i based on bootstrap carousel)

My html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="carousel carousel-showmanymoveone slide vertical" id="carousel123">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/50/0054A6/fff/&amp;text=1" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/50/002d5a/fff/&amp;text=2" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/50/d6d6d6/333&amp;text=3" class="img-responsive"></a></div>
          </div>          
          <div class="item">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3"><a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/50/002040/eeeeee&amp;text=4" class="img-responsive">
          </div>
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel123" data-slide="prev"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel123" data-slide="next"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Js

```
(function(){
  $('.carousel-showmanymoveone .item').each(function(){
    var itemToClone = $(this);
    for (var i=1;i<4;i++) {
      itemToClone = itemToClone.next();
          if (!itemToClone.length) {
        itemToClone = $(this).siblings(':first');
      }
          itemToClone.children(':first-child').clone()
        .addClass("cloneditem-"+(i))
        .appendTo($(this));
    }
  });
}());
```

Problem is that when I press "next" button it overflows next slide, but when I press "prev" button it doesn't show any transition.

I don't know how to make it work properly. Is there any ready to use solution?
It will be working in product page in shop showing product images.

[Bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/Zu976sI7v2)

Comment: well it seems working for me too, please `control + r` with your browser or try with a different one. Incase still any error exist please specify it better here.

Comment: @ErhanYaşar there is bad transition with next slides, and no transition with prev slides, that what I want to change

Comment: well the carousel you choose works like that, I don't have to add more on that. You may try any other carousel instead.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code. It works perfectly fine for next and previous slide. Did you try clearing your web browser's cache? Try doing this! https://kb.iu.edu/d/ahic

Comment: there is bad transition with next slides, and no transition with prev slides, that what I want to change